# Is there a way to pass C# string params to an automatically triggered stored procedure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, console-application

I have a C# console app that's connected to PostgreSQL using Npgsql. My goal is to **audit** every action that a logged in user performs on a table ("Usuarios"), is automatically audited (copied with some extra data) to another table called ("Auditoria_Usuarios"). I've decided to use a stored procedure to accomplish this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditarUsuarios() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $auditoria_usuarios$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO auditoria_usuarios SELECT 'B', now(), usuarioLogueado, OLD.*;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO auditoria_usuarios SELECT 'M', now(), usuarioLogueado, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO auditoria_usuarios SELECT 'A', now(), usuarioLogueado, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$auditoria_usuarios$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER auditoria_usuarios
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE auditarUsuarios();
```

The previously mentioned tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    usuarioID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username text,
    password text,
    email text,
    nombre text,
    apellido text,
    estado bool
);

CREATE TABLE auditoria_usuarios(
    operacion char(1) NOT NULL,
    fechahora timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid text NOT NULL,
    username text,
    password text,
    email text,
    nombre text,
    apellido text,
    estado bool
);
```

Now, I want the "usuarioLogueado" variable, to be "passed in as a parameter" from the C# Console Application. This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Npgsql;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Database_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string usuarioLogueado = "userThatIsLoggedIn";
            string connectionString = "User ID=someDBUser;Password=somePassword;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=modulo_de_seguridad;commandTimeout=900";
            NpgsqlConnection Connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Intentando conectar...");
                Connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Conexion exitosa");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

I want that C# "string" variable called "usuarioLogueado" to be passed as a parameter to the "auditarUsuarios()" stored procedure, for it to save the "logged in-the-app user" as "userid" in the "auditoria_usuarios" table. I wondered if there's any piece of C# code to make that in-app variable reach the stored procedure's parameter ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97095/set-session-custom-variable-to-store-user-id Could be helpful; i'm thinking you can maybe have a subclass or provider/factory that will make a command and prefix it with a line that sets a session variable or runs a command that sets the var for the connection so anything else that uses it gets that variable too.. not a Postgres developer, so I've never done it but I've missed on the possibility quite a few times of doing something similar for sql server

Comment: Thanks for the comment @CaiusJard ! I'm not being able to implement what the post you attached suggests... Whenever I try to "set "modulo_de_seguridad.user" to "someUsername"; FROM THE APP , it runs correctly but doesn't apply the changes. Despite this, If I run it from pgAdmin4, it works. (I do need it to work from the app though)
"